# Is it possible to control the LED on Apple Wireless Keyboard on Linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard, bluetooth

I use an Apple Wireless Keyboard on Linux 3.0 and have remapped the CapsLock Key and use it frequently now and would like to turn off the LED as it has lost its function.
There is [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/285103/is-it-possible-to-control-the-caps-lock-led-on-os-x) regarding this for Mac OS X and it seems possible to access the LED through IOKit.

Does the Linux hid_apple driver offer the same capabilities? I couldn't find any relevant setting in `/sys/module/hid_apple/`.

Comment: <obvious> You could tape over the light, if it really bothers you that much </obvious>. But seriously, there are some things that aren't worth the time - this may or may not be one of them.

Comment: @new123456 Obviously distraction is only one concern, battery drain is another. This is a wireless keyboard after all and Apple even disables the off/on LED, so it might be worth disabling this one as well.